# Setting custom title AND icon for alert dialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, title, typeface

Any idea how to do this? Here is a snippet of my code, the dilemma is I want a custom font for my title, message, and button text for my AlertDialog.builder. The problem is when the dialog appears, there is no icon, the blue default dividing line that supposed to be UNDER the title is above the dialog box, and my custom title is right above the message. The layout is supposed to be:

```
(ICON) (TITLE)
(divider)
(Message)
(button1)(button2)
```

but instead it looks like this:

(divider)

(Title)
(Message)
(button1) (button2)

There is no icon and the divider is above the window...

Here is my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder endGameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
    // Setting Dialog
    endGameDialog.setCancelable(false);
    endGameDialog.setMessage("Do you want to play again?");
```

....

`if (myScore == roundChoice) {
        AlertDialog alert = endGameDialog.create();
        alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        TextView titleV = new TextView(myContext);
        titleV.setTypeface(font);
        titleV.setTextSize(60);
        titleV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        titleV.setShadowLayer(1, 6, -1, redShadow);
        titleV.setText("You won!");
        alert.setCustomTitle(titleV);
        alert.show();
        alert.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alert.getWindow().getAttributes();
        dialog = true;
        Button btn1 = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        Button btn2 = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        TextView messageView = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageView.setTypeface(font);
        messageView.setTextSize(54);
        messageView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        messageView.setShadowLayer(1, 6, -1, redShadow);
        btn1.setTypeface(font);
        btn1.setTextSize(44);
        btn1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn1.setShadowLayer(1, 6, -1, redShadow);
        btn2.setTypeface(font);
        btn2.setTextSize(44);
        btn2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn2.setShadowLayer(1, 6, -1, redShadow);

    }`

Comment: Make a layout and assign it to your custom dialog. See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: I tried that the problem is I hate using xml and my typefaces and texts have to be declared programmatically anyway I'd rather avoid creating a layout especially since I like the default alertdialog best.

Comment: OK. Anyway, on that page is also explained how to do that without xml layouts.

Comment: I would look at the answer @Bob Malooga gave. You really should utilize the Alert Dialog Builder to build your alerts.

Comment: I did...the problem is I can't get my custom fonts other than setting them programmatically in textViews, which is fine it works. I just set a custom title and message by textViews with the font and color. The only problem is that I cant seem to get the icon to show and the default title divider is not positioned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be to make a custom layout and assign it to your custom dialog.
See this for reference: developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

To build an AlertDialog without using a custom layout:

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
       .setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_icon); // Here you set your icon

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

But then I don't know how could you assign a different typeface to the title.

Comment: This doesn't solve my font problem. How can I get my custom font into those strings other than by creating a textView?

Comment: That's why I suggested you to use a custom layout